# How to automatically get IP to my server program?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, arduino

Is there any possibility to obtain IP by DHCP to my server program? I want to create an "receiver" using TCP server to obtain data sent by Arduino.

If'd use `IPAdress.Any` I get `0.0.0.0` IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these piece of code, I think it should give you what you need

```
IPAddress Address = null;
String ServerHostName = "";

ServerHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(ServerHostName);
Address = ipEntry.AddressList[0];
```

Comment: Will it return DNS hostname, right? What if i do not have DNS in local network?

Comment: I don't know sorry, I was browsing and saw your question - I had a similar problem last week so just thought you might be able to use the same code I did. Good luck finding a solution.